# Add keys to ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have three SSH key pairs that I want to have added to the SSH agent every time I start a shell. After restarting I always have to manually add them again by using `ssh-add <path_to_private_key>`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

If you log in through SSH, you can use SSH agent forwarding, by way of the `-A` option to `ssh` (alternatively, you can set an option in your `~/.ssh/config`). Doing this will allow you to copy SSH keys from the server to your locally-running `ssh-agent`.

If you log in through an X session, you should have a single, central `ssh-agent` running, set up by your distribution. If not, make sure your `~/.xsession` (or whatever you use to start your X session) contains something like this:

```
ssh-agent awesome
```

(on the assumption that you're like me and love the awesome window manager).

If all else fails, you could use your `~/.bash_profile`. In there, add something along the following lines (near the *top* of that file):

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ]
then
    exec ssh-agent bash
fi
ssh-add ...
```

this checks if you've already got an agent running; if not, it starts one anew, which then starts a shell. If you do, it adds your keys to it.

(There is another option where you run `eval ssh-agent` without passing it a command to run. Don't do this; it is less secure)

Answer (score -1):

After starting the agent save the commands to set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID` to a file.  Then execute these commands instead of starting the agent again.  This will leave you with one shared agent for all your shells.  Building this functionality in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` file will make this easier.

If you are working in an X-Windows environment, you could just start the agent as part of the X-Windows initialization.  Your shells should then inherit the existing agent settings.

When using this solution, I add the keys with a relatively short timeout.  The default can be set when starting ssh-agent by using the `-t` option.

Comment: having a shared agent for shells who don't share a parent is a bad idea, and there's a simpler solution.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst As it is trivial to steal access to an ssh-agent running as the same user on the same server, I don't see any additional risk.