# Avoid separately adding ssh keys (with password) to shell sessions

Tags: tmux, ssh-agent

Note: Adding a few lines to the `.<name of shell>rc` will not solve the problem here, since this particular ssh key has a password and that would not eliminate the need to keep typing it.

So I don't really understand how `ssh-agent` works under the hood. I just use `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` every time I need to add a key to access some remote resource. One I've added the key once, I don't need to add it again for the same "shell session" ("shell session" is probably not the appropriate jargon).

Unfortunately, I'm creating new shell sessions all the time. I'm running zsh under tmux on OS X and have a ssh key creatively named `id_rsa`. That ssh key has a password associated with it.

Every time I start a new shell I have to do the following

```
$ eval `ssh-agent`
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
<type password>
```

which is really irritating.

I've noticed in the output of `ssh-agent` that the `SSH_AGENT_PID` environment variable is different every time. My hunch is that this environment variable and the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` are the reason that keys don't need to be re-added within a single shell session. When I call the `ssh` program, it will use these environment variables to communicate with the `ssh-agent` and authentication will succeed.

I'm wondering if there's a way of sharing `ssh-agent`s between sessions. Maybe the right approach is to add my SSH keys before starting `tmux` and configure `tmux` to preserve the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID` environment variables. I'm really not sure. What's the standard way of solving this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add keys to ssh-agent](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274913/add-keys-to-ssh-agent)

Comment: @ThomasDickey No. It's vaguely related, but not the same issue and the possible solutions are not the same.

Comment: It's related well enough that some of the answers merely copy from it and similar questions without adding new insight.

Comment: @ThomasDickey A good answer to this question would address the fact that this is OSX, not a system where a session means an X server. This doesn't appear in the duplicate nor in similar questions I can find on this site.

Comment: @Gregory, starting a new agent and running `ssh-add` from the shell startup script would of course require writing the password each time, but making sure you can connect to an existing agent isn't the same. But yes, I admit to missing the mention of OS X.

Comment: Related thought: is it common for other Unixes (or Linuxes) apart from OS X to start an ssh-agent on login by default? Is the usual case that the user has to do it, or is this something that would commonly be preconfigured?

Comment: There are desktop utilities which do this, some with more success than others.  I've not found those useful.

Comment: A similar question with (I think) a slightly better answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132117/161288 (same author as [the one here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299203/161288)) because it uses `ssh`'s own tools and designated exit codes to check the socket is working. I use a hybrid of the two.

Answer (score 9):

The way ssh-agent is intended to work is that you have one agent per session. The agent starts and ends with the session.

A session starts when you log in, not when you open a terminal or when you start a shell. Systematically running `ssh-agent` as part of your shell startup script is definitely wrong.

I'm not an OSX user so I may be missing something, but to my understanding, on non-ancient OSX versions (since 10.5), SSH is integrated with the OSX keychain. So you shouldn't run `ssh-agent` at all. The `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable should point to a launchd socket (launchd provides an ssh-agent service). See [How to use Mac OS X Keychain with SSH keys?](https://superuser.com/questions/88470/how-to-use-mac-os-x-keychain-with-ssh-keys) and [How to prevent ssh from adding my key to ssh-agent on Snow Leopard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13595/how-to-prevent-ssh-from-adding-my-key-to-ssh-agent-on-snow-leopard/13710#13710)

If you want to stick with `ssh-agent` for some reason, and you want to have a single agent for all sessions (which also makes sense), you can use a fixed path for the SSH socket. (I've done that on Windows.) In your `.profile`, set `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to a fixed path, and start `ssh-agent` if it isn't already running.

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/auth_sock
if ! fuser "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  # Nothing has the socket open, it means the agent isn't running
  ssh-agent -a "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" -s >~/.ssh/agent-info
fi
```

Note that my code doesn't try to kill the agent. If you want to kill the agent when you log out, add a kill instruction to your logout scripts. Of course, if you kill all the processes running as your user, that includes the agent.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a little snippet from my login scripts to handle what you want:

```
SSHAF=$HOME/.ssh_agent_env
[ -f $SSHAF ] && . $SSHAF

# if ssh-agent not really running?
if [ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ] && ! kill -0 $SSH_AGENT_PID >/dev/null
then ssh-agent >$SSHAF 
     . $SSHAF
     ssh-add # add list of more keys here if needed
fi
```

Explained:
I'm saving the environment setting variables from ssh-agent in a dotfile in $HOME (.ssh_agent_env)
I source that file if it exists (line 2) to get the process id of the (possibly) running ssh-agent. (SSH_AGENT_PID variable)
If that SSH_AGENT_PID variable is set, I check to see if the agent is running with a kill -0 on it's PID (kill -0 sets return code to 0 (true) if the process is running, 1 (false) otherwise.
If the agent isn't running I start it and save the output in the .ssh_agent_env file, source that file to add the values to my shell session, and run ssh-add to cache my keys.

The first time on the system, no file exists so the agent is started.
Any time after that the file exists, we verify if the agent is running. If not we do a startup.

Note: this is my running implementation of the solution 2 of the first answer above.

Comment: By default answers are ordered by votes (and randomized on page load in case of ties), so “first answer above” changes over time. If you refer to other answers, you should use a link and not refer to position.

Comment: I think that [a fixed path to the socket](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299203) is simpler than storing the socket name from a file.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what `ssh-agent` does, is that it starts itself in the background, and prints a bunch of environment variables that the `ssh` client utility uses to know how to reach the agent (mostly the path of the socket in `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`). If you start the agent again, you get multiple copies running, but you can usually reach only one from a single shell... (check with something like `ps uax | grep agent` to see how many you are running.) When `ssh-add` is run, it contacts the agent, and asks it to read a key to memory. After that any `ssh` clients that connect to the same `ssh-agent` instance can take advantage of the saved key.

---

Couple of choices to run only one `ssh-agent`:

1) Start `ssh-agent` before you start your `tmux` session (or `screen` for that matter). The environment variables set at that point should be inherited to all shells you run under `tmux` or `screen`. (I don't know if `tmux` needs special configuration to not clean environment variables.)

I've been (the wrong type of) lazy, so I've  just done that manually each time before starting my `screen` session, but it would be easy to create a script to both start the agent and then the `screen`/`tmux` session.

If you consider something like a graphical desktop environment, you should start the agent when the DE starts, if possible, so that the environment variables will be available to any terminals you start.

2) Your system may already start an `ssh-agent` when you log in. In that case you should be able to just `ssh-add` keys to it without starting a new copy of the agent. In particular OS X starts an agent when logging in, and has modified SSH tools that ask for the key passphrase through the GUI and automatically save keys used on the `ssh` command to the agent. You can also use `ssh-add` as usual.

3) If you want to use a single agent from completely separate shells (and therefore cannot inherit the environment variables), check if the agent is running from your shell's startup scripts, and start it if not. Either save the agent's socket address to a file, or use a fixed path to the socket.

---

In any case, the issue is with pointing the environment variables to the same `ssh-agent`. Any keys you add to one instance of the agent should be visible to all users of the same agent, regardless of if what shell you `ssh-add` them from.

As an aside, `ssh-add` can take an argument to define how long the keys shall be saved: running `ssh-add -t 3600 my-key-file` will tell the agent to forget about the key after an hour. This may be useful to reduce the time during which the keys are unencrypted in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The primary variable is the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable; the `SSH_AGENT_PID` is only used with `ssh-agent -k` to kill the running agent.

So the standard approach is to run `ssh-agent`, then `ssh-add` your keys, then run `tmux`.

Now the fun part of this is that you can *reconnect* to the `tmux` daemon and your ssh agent session will still be there and running.  So you can do things like disconnect, logout, login again, reconnect to running tmux and not need to re-enter your key password.

(This is good on a single-user machine; not so good on a shared machine 'cos the `root` user could abuse your keys!)

Comment: If you don't trust root, you've lost already, you shouldn't have private keys or type passwords on that machine. Loading the keys into the agent doesn't make things worse.

Comment: It is far far simpler for `root` to do `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/your/socket` than it is for him to steal key presses.  I've plenty of experience of SAs with the first level of knowledge than of the second and many data leaks have been "simple".  Security isn't binary :-)

Comment: Granted, I've known sysadmins who couldn't google “keylogger” with both hands too. But that doesn't really make the bar higher. Incompetent sysadmins is something you should expect but not something you can rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd start `ssh-agent` only once, and run `ssh-add` only once, and the subsequent shells will inherit the agent.

If you're logging in through a GUI and your window manager uses `.xsession` or `.xinitrc`, you may add the following to that file:

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
  eval $(ssh-agent)
  ssh-add
fi
```

This means that the agent will be inherited for any process (`xterm` or other terminal emulator) that the window manager spawns.

If you work without X11, then feel happy for a bit because you're awesome, and then add those lines to your `.bash_profile` or `.profile` shell initialization script.

The `eval` will take the output from `ssh-agent` and evaluate it in the current shell, setting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID` to whatever the values are. Then `ssh-add` will be run, pretty much as you're doing manually. The agent will then be inherited by the `tmux` session you're likely to start soon after logging in (unless you've set `tmux` to be your actual login shell, which is possible).

In a perfect world, you then only have one running SSH agent and won't have to give any passwords ever again... until you log out and in again, or log in on another console.